# Shell - Awk - If with variables

Tags: shell, awk

I have a problem with my shell script. The thing I need is something like this: How can I compare variable in if condition in awk argument. "If $variable is same as the third column $3 .. print the third column". It doesn't work for me.

```
variable=large
awk '{if ($3 == $variable) print "\n" $3}' temp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
variable=large
awk -v var="$variable" '{if ($3 == var) print "\n" $3}' temp
```

Comment: So the problem depends on the "-v" ?

Comment: @user3456898 to be honest, the problem is you didn't read the man page carefully, and didn't do a google. `-v` option is explained as the 3rd option in man page. also this kind of question has been asked many times.

Comment: @user3456898 You can also use variable at the end, but read the man to see why/why not. `awk '{if ($3 == var) print "\n" $3}' var="$variable" temp`. And always double quote variables.